# Carrying the contents of a label from one view controller to another

Tags: ios

I am creating a simple iOS game that has a counter that tracks the users score and presents it in a UILabel in the corner of the screen. When something happens in the game it switches to a game over screen. I want to then display the contents of the label from the previous view in  a label in the new view as the players score.

I feel there should be an easy way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that you've embedded your game logic into your user interface.  The score is not part of the user interface, but you've put it there anyway.

If your game is *really* simple, add a property to your app delegate that keeps track of the score.  Each part of your user interface can access that property when it needs to.

As soon as you go beyond the most simple game possible, you should factor out your game logic into its own class.  That class is responsible for managing the game state.  Instantiate it when you start a new game, and you can pass it through to view controllers, create a shared instance, etc.

I'd recommend reading up on [MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1).

Comment: Okay, thanks for you help. I think my game probably is simple enough to keep the game logic in the user interface, but I will definitely think about making a separate class in the future. May I just ask though, what is the issue with doing it the way I have?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the label a `@property` and use `self.navigationController.presentingViewController` or something similar to access the first view controller:

```
@interface ViewControllerOne : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabelOne;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabelOne;

@end


@interface ViewControllerTwo : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabelTwo;
}

// myLabelTwo doesnt need to be a property, it could just be an ivar.  Up to you.
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabelTwo;

@end

@implementation ViewControllerTwo

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myLabelTwo.text = [(ViewControllerOne *)self.navigationController.presentingViewController myLabelOne].text;
}


@end
```

[`UINavigationController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[`UIViewController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[Properties in Objective-C 2.0](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103)

Comment: Okay thanks. I tried this, but `self.endScore.text = [(Meteor_FieldViewController *)self.navigationController.presentingViewController score].text;
` was giving me the error _Member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union_

Comment: Thats a weird error.. can you put some more of that code and full error/stack trace in your question so I can see it a little better?

Answer (score 0):

Step away from your views for a second. Your labels and any other views are a place to present data, not to store it. What you want to share across screens is the score, which is part of your player's state.

Create a `Player` object. Give it a `score` property. Pass the same `Player` instance to the controllers of both views. Now you have a model shared by multiple controllers and presented in many views. Either controller can potentially update the model and the other with have access to the new state for display in their views.

Comment: Okay, I will have a go at doing that. Thank you for your help Jonah!